# Is there a relation between these words?

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to know about the difference or relation or are they same:

Interpolating geometry; is a system of generators such that given distinct points no two of them have same first coordinates, there is a unique curve in the geometry passing through these points.

For example: If there are two points it is a projective plane.

Incidence geometry: is a system consisting of two nonempty sets, the elements of one being called points and those of the other lines, together with a relation, called incidence.

What is the ralation?...

Thanks.

Comment: *For example: If there are two points it is a projective plane.* This is very confusing. It sounds like a single vertical line in $\Bbb R^2$ satisfies your first thing, but it is certainly not a plane and not a projective plane.

Comment: Not only that some other conditions should satisfy for the Projective plane. Also for the three points its a Laguerre plane with some other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In incidence geometry, the *incidence relation* $\mathcal R\subseteq \mathcal P\times\mathcal L$ tells you when a point $p$ lies on a line $\ell$. If $(p,\ell)\in \mathcal R$, then the point $p$ is on the line $\ell$.

"Interpolation geometry" got no relevant hits on google, so I'm not really sure what you mean. But at any rate, the words "curve $\ell$ passing through the points $x,y$" looks like a rewriting of "$x$ and $y$ are incident on the line $\ell$."

Geometry authors often freely switch descriptions of incidence in order to avoid sounding terribly boring. "$p$ is on/lies on $\ell$" and "$\ell$ passes\goes through $p$" all mean the same thing, that $p$ is incident on $\ell$.

Comment: That's true. I couldn't find the term interpolating geometry in google or any other. I think as you told both are same. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Ryan They're impossible to compare because the first one discusses coordinates and the second one does not.